# Assigning elements to a list using for loop?

Tags: python

I have to figure out which is larger, the first or last element in a given list, and set all the other elements to be that value.

I wrote a code using a for loop, but I get an error that the list index is out of range.  What is my mistake?

The code is below:

```
def max_end3(nums):
    for i in nums:
        if (nums[0] > nums[len(nums)-1]):
            nums[i] = nums[0]
        else:
            nums[i] = nums[len(nums)-1]
        return (nums)
```

Comment: `for i in nums` / `nums[i]` is not the proper way to *index* the list `nums`.

Comment: `i` is not an index, it is the number (the list element) itself.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but here is one way to achieve your aim: `nums[:] = [max(nums[0], nums[-1])]*len(nums)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option:

```
the_list = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 7]

val = max([the_list[0], the_list[-1])

the_list = [val]*len(the_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've confused an index with a list element.  Consider the input list [17, 3, -42, -3].  Your `for` statement steps `i` through the values 17, 3, -42, and -3, in that order.  However, the assignments you do assume that `i` is taking on the *position* or index values, 0, 1, 2, 3.

Try this, instead:

```
def max_end3(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if (nums[0] > nums[len(nums)-1]):
            nums[i] = nums[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do for loop since `'nums` is already a list. I believe coding bat is giving array length is 3. So try this

```
def max_end3(nums):
  if nums[0] > nums[-1]:
    return nums[:1] *3
  elif nums[-1] > nums[0]:
    return nums[-1:] * 3
  elif nums[0] == nums[-1]:
    return nums[:1] * 3
  else:
    return nums
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in nums` / `nums[i]` is not the proper way to *index* the list `nums`. I think you can try this instead:

```
def max_end3(nums):
    for i,num in enumerate(nums):
        if (nums[0] > nums[-1]):
            nums[i] = nums[0]
        else:
            nums[i] = nums[-1]
    return (nums)
```

Use the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to return "a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over sequence." This allows you to concurrently index & iterate the values.

Use `nums[-1]` to represent the *last* item in the list, since Python supports negative indexing :)

Note: other solutions are more elegant, and this is *not* how I would solve the problem, but for a beginner it is sometimes easier to understand if working with simple constructs like `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To replace each element in the given list I would pre-compute the wanted value, and then assign it to each element, thus:

```
def max_end3(nums):
    larger = max((nums[0], nums[-1]))
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = larger
```

You could alternatively leave the original list unchanged, and generate a new list of the wanted values. If the new list is assigned to the same name as the old one, it will have a similar effect, eg.

```
nums = [max((nums[0], nums[-1]))] * len(nums)
```